# Issue while running dbt model in redshift with analyze

Tags: amazon-redshift, dbt

I would like to know if anyone had faced a similar issue.

I got a model that the create works fine but in dbt fails, here are the logs

```
22:06:02 SQL status: SUCCESS in 0.0 seconds
22:06:02 Using redshift connection "model.company_dbt.bin_1938_final_data"
22:06:02 On model.company_dbt.bin_1938_final_data: create table query
22:08:15 SQL status: SUCCESS in 133.0 seconds
22:08:15 Using redshift connection "model.company_dbt.bin_1938_final_data"
22:08:15 On model.company_dbt.bin_1938_final_data: alter table "analytics"."dbt_company_dev"."bin_1938_final_data__dbt_tmp" rename to "bin_1938_final_data"
22:08:15 SQL status: SUCCESS in 0.0 seconds
22:08:15 Using redshift connection "model.company_dbt.bin_1938_final_data"
22:08:15 On model.company_dbt.bin_1938_final_data: ANALYZE bin_1938_final_data
22:08:15 Redshift adapter: Redshift error: relation "bin_1938_final_data" does not exist
22:08:15 On model.company_dbt.bin_1938_final_data: ROLLBACK
22:08:15 Timing info for model.company_dbt.bin_1938_final_data (execute): 22:06:02.182898 => 22:08:15.676357
22:08:15 On model.company_dbt.bin_1938_final_data: Close
```

Here are the configs of my model:

```
{{ config(
    materialized='table',
    alias='bin_1938_final_data',
    dist='customer_id',
    sort=['customer_id', 'range_date'],
    post_hook=['ANALYZE bin_1938_final_data']
)
}}
```

Has someone faced something similar?

Thanks.

Comment: Found the issue, looks like post_hook on Redshift runs sometimes before finishing the model work.
Updated the config as follows seems to solve the issue:

`
{{ config(
    materialized='table',
    alias='bin_1938_final_data',
    dist='customer_id',
    sort=['range_date', 'customer_id'],
    sort_type='interleaved',
    post_hook=after_commit('ANALYZE {{ schema }}.bin_1938_final_data')
)
}}
`